# Pgadmin3 Crashes Too Often on OSX

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am using pgAdmin3 on my OSX 10.10.5 and I find crash so many times, for example when I try to show table data.

What I do so far is remove the `~/.pgadmin_histoqueries` that's definitely solve the problem, only for a while before the same problem come again.

Is there any permanent solution for this? thank you.

Comment: Probably best to ask this on Server Fault unless your planning on making code changes to fix the issue.

Comment: Only advice I can give is: fetch the latest version as source and compile it.  http://www.pgadmin.org/

Comment: @joop I have tried once and no luck.